# how to automatically use the session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, authorization

please help to deal with the authorization through the script. the problem is that it is impossible to automatically insert a get-request invbf_session_id.

```
import pprint
import requests
import re
import shelve

import bs4


def scanning_posts():
    print('------------------------enter begin--------------------')

    url = 'http://forum.saransk.ru/'
    html = requests.get(url)

    pprint.pprint(html.headers)
    rawCookie = html.headers['Set-Cookie']
    cookie = re.search(r"invbf_session_id=(.*?);", rawCookie).group(1)
    pprint.pprint(cookie)   # cookie != zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text)
    loginForm = soup.find('form', {'id': 'login'})
    hiddenAuthKey = soup.find('input', {'name': 'auth_key'})['value']

    authData = {    
                'ips_username': 'xxxxxx',
                'ips_password': 'yyyyyy',
                'auth_key': hiddenAuthKey,
                'rememberMe': 1,
                'referer':  'http://forum.saransk.ru/'
    }

    header = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36',
                'Referer': 'http://forum.saransk.ru/forum/'
    }

    #pprint.pprint(authData)
    print('\tlogin: ', authData['ips_username'])

    cookie = dict(invbf_session_id='zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz')



    req = requests.get(url, params=authData, cookies=cookie, headers=header)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text)

    signLinkNotLogged = soup.find('a', {'id': 'sign_in'})
    if signLinkNotLogged:
        print('------------------------enter failed--------------------')
    else:
        print('------------------------enter successful--------------------')


scanning_posts()
```

After running the script displays the wrong value invbf_session_id, as seen in FF firebug. respectively, authorization is not obtained.

if the value invbf_session_id copy of FF firebug and paste the script, the authorization is successful

Comment: I think the answer is more complex thank you'd think. You're fetching `invbf_session_id` and it doesn't work.. But when you use the same variable name from `FireFox` it does work? So what's the difference if you're inputting the same variable? Well my guess is the fact that FireFox keeps track of **other** session variables as well. You'll need to mimic the exact `POST` values as `FireFox` sends in order to achive a automatic login. So whatever the server throws at you to "keep track of", you do, and you send those session variables along with `invbf_session_id` which is one of many.

Comment: A good idea is also to use `Wireshark` in order to see the actual difference between **your** post and **FireFox's* post requests. Because ther IS a difference in them for sure.. Just hard to tell from your code and since we don't know what the sever's "input" fields and headers are.

Comment: Why not use `request.Session()` to handle cookies for you?